# Use react navigation.navigate inside a normal function - (no hooks allowed i.e. useNavigation)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to put a function that navigates to a screen in an other module and export it, but `navigation` does not work. I tried with `UseNavigation()` but I get an error, namely: `Unhandled promise rejection: Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.`

Is there a way to use navigation in a normal function, or anything else.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { AsyncStorage, Alert } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "react-navigation-hooks";

export const startMixGame = async (categoryIsChosen, withTimer) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  if (categoryIsChosen) {
    if (withTimer) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("useTimer", "true");
      navigation.navigate({
        routeName: "MixedQuestions",
        params: {
          categoryId: "1"
        }
      });
    } else if (!withTimer) {
      // console.log("withTimer", withTimer);

      await AsyncStorage.setItem("useTimer", "false");
      navigation.navigate({
        routeName: "NoTimerMixedQuestions",
        params: {
          categoryId: "1"
        }
      });
    }
  }

};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a singleton service holding a reference to the navigation, at the root of your app save with a useEffect the reference in the singleton, so you can you it everywhere.
Something like this:

```
class NavigationService {
  constructor() {
    this._navigation = null;
  }

  set navigation(nav) {
    this._navigation = nav;
  }

  get navigation() {
    return this._navigation;
  }
}

const navigationService = new NavigationService();

export default navigationService;
```

and in your main screen / view

```
    const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
      useEffect(() => {
        navigationService.navigation = navigation;
      }, [navigation]);
   ....
```

and now everywhere you can do this

```
import navigationService from '../services/navigation';

navigationService.navigation.navigate('Screen');
```

Comment: Hello @Antonio, thanks for the reply. I tried to use your code, but I get an error: `Invariant Violation: Render more hooks than during the previous render`. It's the `useEffect` in the App.js, right? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: `Invariant Violation: Render more hooks than during the previous render`  @Fotis Tsakiris you should always create all hooks before any other code in the functional component. I mean make sure all hooks are rendered all the time. do not create a hook in conditions

Comment: @ Antonio, OK fixed that, thnks! Now I get an other error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating _NavigationService.default.navigation.navigate)` that's coming from the file where I use the navigation. Could there be something wrong with the way I import it? I do: `import navigationService from '../../../NavigationService';` because there is where to be found. I don't have to do `import navigationService from '../services/navigation';` (like you do) right? Moreover, I also import it in the `HomeScreen `!

Comment: Don't use the navigationService before your root component is mounted, otherwise the hook will not fire the navigation var registration. Try to put a condition before using the navigation, like `if (navigationService.navigation !== null) ...` and print a console log if it is null

Comment: Thanks a lot Antonio. It's working! I'm sorry for the fuss. I got a bit confused with the `HomeScreen`. I thought I had to put the `useEffect` in the `App.js` where the app starts. But I just realized, that the `App.js` does not have a `navigation` property! So I moved it to the component where the button lives, and it's done! Thanks again! Happy coding ;

Answer (score 0):

check this
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

you can save a reference to NavigationContainer and use it to navigate.

**App**

```js
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator'
...
render (){
 return (<AppNavigator/>)
}
```

**AppNavigator**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import AppStack from './AppStack';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import NavigationService from './NavigationService';

const AppNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer
            ref={NavigationService.instance}
        >
            <AppStack/>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
export default AppNavigator
```

**AppStack**

```js
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export default () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>

             // add all screens here
             <Stack.Screen
                name={'Home'}
                component={HomeCpmponent}
            />

        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

```js
import {NavigationContainerRef} from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as React from 'react';
import {boundClass} from 'autobind-decorator';

@boundClass
class NavigationService {
    instance = React.createRef<NavigationContainerRef>();

    dispatch(action) {
        this.instance.current?.dispatch(action)
    }

    getInstance() {
        return this.instance?.current
    }

    canGoBack() {
        return this.getInstance()?.canGoBack()
    }

    navigate(routeName: string, params: any) {
        return this.getInstance()?.navigate(routeName, params)
    }

}

export default new NavigationService()
```

You can use `NavigationService.dispatch()` and `import {CommonActions, StackActions} from '@react-navigation/native';`
 or `NavigationService.navigate('home',{id:'test1'})` or ...

Comment: Hello @Ahmad, thanks for the reply, but I get two errors: 1. Even though in the docs they also use in `App.js` a function component I get: `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?%s%s, `. 2. In the `RootNavigation.js` the `?` gives error `Expression expected`. If I delete it, the app runs, but when I use the func I get `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'navigationRef.current.navigate)`. BTW I use `import NavigationContainer from './navigation/NavigationContainer';
`. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I cannot follow up. Moreover, it seams to me like I have to change my navigation system a lot! Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, now that I see it again, I could just pass the `navigation` as a argument/parameter, like:

```js
export const startMixGame = async (categoryIsChosen, navigation, withTimer) => { ...}
```